# Need Python Programming Tips

Tags: python, mysql, class, optimization, connection

I'm learning python since last few weeks. For better learning, I decided to work on some project. So here is my Class for MySQL connection and demo example as well. Can you please tell me. What other improvement can be possible for following code?

- Structure?
- What else I can do to optimize code?

And Please forgive. If I'm doing some silly mistakes in code. (I'm learning)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pymysql

# select (table, parameter)
# insert (table, data)
# update (table, id, data)
# delete (table, id)

class MySQL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sort_by = ""
        self.order = ""
        # initiate database connection.
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='sherlock',
                             charset='utf8mb4')

        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    # this function is for selecting any feild on any table.(feilds veriable is optinal)     
    def select(self, table, *feilds):
        flds = "" #differnt name for feilds veriable.
        if not feilds:
            flds = '*'
        else:
            for f in feilds:
                if not flds:
                    flds = f
                else:
                    flds += ",`%s`" % f
        sql = "SELECT %s FROM `%s` " % (flds, table)
        if self.sort_by:
            sql = sql +"order by "+ str(self.sort_by) +" "+ str(self.order)
        print sql
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        result = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return result    

    # This function is for data sorting for Mysql; but optinal.
    # example : SELECT * FROM `users`  order by id asc
    def order_by(self, sort_by="", order="", *args, **kwargs):
        self.sort_by = sort_by
        self.order = order

    # this function is for closing Mysql connection
    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()

########### END OF MySQL CLASS #############


sql = MySQL()

# sql.order_by function should be called before the sql.select() function.
sql.order_by("email")

# this will select all the feilds from `users` table.
# you can specify whichever feilds you want to return. like : sql.select("users", "id, email")
result = sql.select("users", "password")

for email in result:
    print email["password"]
sql.close()
```

Comment: You can alternately post this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Whoa!! That's great!! Thanks Buddy...

Comment: You're very welcome :-)

Comment: Can you suggest for code optimization ? like is this the correct of function-parameters?